# What is curried tapenade?

Tags: language, curry

I have just watched the A-Team film and B.A. seems to have an obsession with something called Curried Tapenade? My experience of Tapenade is that it's a Olive based dish and making a curried version sounds horrible. Does anyone who what Curried Tapenade actually is?

Comment: Does anyone know where I can get a real light-saber? I saw these in a movie once. My plastic one makes cool noises but cannot actually cut someone's hand off. Halp! :-D

Comment: Are they talking about the bastardized English definition of curry or the Indian origin of the word?

Answer (score 5):

It is a joke. Coconut curry tapenade with toast points is ridiculous to begin with, and it is intended to be funny that a big burly man craves something that is supposed to sound dainty? or elegant?

I'm sure you can quite possibly make a dish and call it this. However, I can't imagine olives, coconut milk, and curry tasting very good.

Comment: A CHALLENGE HAS BEEN ISSUED. I will report back with results. (I agree that viscerally it sounds kinda gross... but if you look at the olives as more of a vehicle for salt and acid, suddenly it begins to make sense.)

Comment: @daniel So much win! :'D Do post your results in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Ingredients (per a person) ;
20 drained, anchovy stuffed green olives
5-10 drained capers
5mm tubed ground garlic
1 Tbsp extra virgin olive oil
1.5 tsp curry powder
4 Tbsp coconut milk powder
fish sauce to taste
4 twigs of fresh parsley
3 leaves of red chicory
2 slices of bread (& butter) [or chips]

Directions ;
1. Place the olives, capers, garlic and olive oil into a blender or food processor; pulse to mince.
2. Add the curry powder and coconut milk powder. Blend until smooth.
3. Season to taste with fish sauce.
4. Mix chopped fresh parsley.
5. Scrape the paste onto a dish. Stand chicory at the center.
6. Toast the bread. Spread butter and cut into the triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of the word curry basically meant a sauce meant for service of rice. The bastardized english variant generally means smothering meat and rice in a sauce made from curry powder.

A tapenade is a seasoned paste of olives, capers, and anchovies.

So it could be simply tapenade that has been adjusted in texture and intensity to be used over rice, or it could mean that it is tapenade with curry powder added. Or it could just be a fancy name of a dish that the screenwriter thought would impress the movie audience.

Comment: Yeah, I think hobodave has it right, just a dumb joke.

Answer (score 1):

Murdock was also known for mixing ingredients, such as the Anti-freeze marinade with gun powder seasoning for steaks, so chances are it's something odd that he came up with and BA happens to love. BA also likes his steaks "burnt, like it was damned" so maybe their tastes are strange but similar.